# Setting TableCell to its editing state without clicking on it

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am trying to call `startEdit()` for a `TableCell`.

I have a Button that inserts a *blank* object / row into the TableView at the first index. The user would then type in the name, address, etc... 
then press enter to *create* the object.

---

I need the `startEdit()` method to be called so each cell in the first row would enter its editing state.

I am trying:

```
 public void edit(int row, TableColumn<S,?> column)
```

But my `TableCells` in the first row are not going into their editing state, or the same state as if `startEdit()` was called on them. The Graphic(TextField) is not being displayed as if i were to click on cell.

```
tableView.edit(0, tableView.getColumns().get(0));

//tableView only has one column right now
```

---

> @Javadocs for TableView.edit();
>
> ```
>   Causes the cell at the given row/column view indexes to switch into
>   its editing state, if it is not already in it, and assuming that the
>   TableView and column are also editable.
> ```

I dont understand how this method switches the cell at the `TablePosition` to its editing state?

---

if `tableView.edit()` cannot put cells in the same state as `startEdit().` How else can I do so?

**Update** Clicking on the cell after i call edit() only requires one click to show textfield. The other cells where i dont call edit() it requires two.

**all `TableColumns`, `TableRows`, `TableCells`, and my `TableView` are set to editable.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this error. The `TextField` in the cell is not focused but otherwise it's in the editing state after using `TableView.edit`. What JavaFX version are you using?

Comment: @fabian FX8 (1.8.0_121)

Comment: @fabian I was setting setGraphic(null); in updateItem of cell.